# Unexpected behavior in Julia boolean comparison

Tags: julia, logistic-regression, boolean-expression

I'm testing different parametrization of the CDF of the logistic function and comparing the results and the effect on the curve of the different parameters.

```
using Distributions

# Vector of x to test the different functions
x = collect(0:20)

Logis = Logistic(10, 1)  # PDF of Logistic function in Julia
y = cdf(Logis, x)       # CDF of Logistic function in Julia

# This is a standard representation of the CDF for Logistic
LogisticV1(x, μ=10, θ=1) = 1 / ( 1 + e^-((x-μ)/θ))   
y1 = LogisticV1.(x)

# This is another representation of the CDF for Logistic
LogisticV2(x, μ=10, θ=1) = 1/2 + 1/2 * tanh((x-μ)/2*θ)
y2 = LogisticV2.(x)
```

The plots of all three functions are identical, as expected. The type of all three y vectors is also the same (Array{Float64,1}) and the three y vectors also appear to be identical.

```
show(y)
```

[4.53979e-5, 0.000123395, 0.00033535, 0.000911051, 0.00247262, 0.00669285, 0.0179862, 0.0474259, 0.119203, 0.268941, 0.5, 0.731059, 0.880797, 0.952574, 0.982014, 0.993307, 0.997527, 0.999089, 0.999665, 0.999877, 0.999955]

```
show(y1)
```

[4.53979e-5, 0.000123395, 0.00033535, 0.000911051, 0.00247262, 0.00669285, 0.0179862, 0.0474259, 0.119203, 0.268941, 0.5, 0.731059, 0.880797, 0.952574, 0.982014, 0.993307, 0.997527, 0.999089, 0.999665, 0.999877, 0.999955]

```
show(y2)
```

[4.53979e-5, 0.000123395, 0.00033535, 0.000911051, 0.00247262, 0.00669285, 0.0179862, 0.0474259, 0.119203, 0.268941, 0.5, 0.731059, 0.880797, 0.952574, 0.982014, 0.993307, 0.997527, 0.999089, 0.999665, 0.999877, 0.999955]

However:

```
y == y1    # true
y == y2    # false
y1 == y2   # false
```

Why is this happening? I assume this has something to do with floating point variations introduced by the tanh function in LogisticV2, but I'm not sure. I appreciate any insight into this.

EDIT: Fixed some typos to make code runnable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare floating point numbers use `isapprox` rather than `==`.

In your case, you will see that `isapprox(y,y1) == isapprox(y,y2) == isapprox(y1,y2) == true`. Furthermore, you can check `maximum(abs.(y-y2))` to see that the difference is of the order of floating point precision (I find `1.1102230246251565e-16`). (Note, however, that `isapprox` by default checks the relative deviation)

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this has something to do with floating point variations introduced by the tanh function in LogisticV2

You are correct:

```
julia> (y .== y1)'
1×21 RowVector{Bool,BitArray{1}}:
 true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true  true

julia> (y .== y2)'
1×21 RowVector{Bool,BitArray{1}}:
 false  false  false  false  false  false  false  false  false  true  true  true  false  false  true  false  false  true  false  false  false
```

But:

```
julia> y ≈ y2    # \approx<TAB> for: ≈ symbol
true
```

`≈` is an Unicode alias for `isapprox`:

> help?> ≈
>
> "≈" can be typed by \approx
>
> search: ≈
>
> `isapprox(x, y; rtol::Real=sqrt(eps), atol::Real=0, nans::Bool=false, norm::Function)`
>
> Inexact equality comparison: `true` if `norm(x-y) <= atol + tol*max(norm(x), norm(y))`. The default `atol` is zero and the default `rtol` depends on   the types of `x` and `y`. The keyword argument nans determines whether or not NaN values are considered equal (defaults to false).
>
> For real or complex floating-point values, `rtol` defaults to
>    `sqrt(eps(typeof(real(x-y))))`. This corresponds to requiring equality
>    of about half   of the significand digits. For other types, `rtol`
>    defaults to zero.
>
> `x` and `y` may also be arrays of numbers, in which case `norm` defaults
>   to `vecnorm` but may be changed by passing a `norm::Function` keyword
>   argument.   (For numbers, `norm` is the same thing as `abs`.) When `x` and `y`
>   are arrays, if `norm(x-y)` is not finite (i.e. `±Inf` or `NaN`), the
>   comparison falls back   to checking whether all elements of `x` and `y`
>   are approximately equal component-wise.
>
> The binary operator `≈` is equivalent to `isapprox` with the default arguments, and `x ≉ y` is equivalent to `!isapprox(x,y)`.
>
> ```
> julia> 0.1 ≈ (0.1 - 1e-10)   
> true
>
> julia> isapprox(10, 11; atol = 2)
> true
>
> julia> isapprox([10.0^9, 1.0], [10.0^9, 2.0])   
> true
> ```